# How to enter space between a continuous string array in PHP using array functions?

Tags: php, arrays, string, space, continuous

Suppose I have a string "stackoverflowdescription" and i have converted into array using str_split, now a want to put space in between each word say "stack over flow description" using array and string functions.

Ex: stackoverflowdescription --> noitpircsedwolfrevokcats --> noitpircsed wolf revo kcats --> stack over flow description

Comment: [`join`](http://php.net/join)?

Comment: And who will decides that `over` & `flow` is different word & not `overflow` ? :p

Comment: Why are you trying to do this ? Describe the complete scenario.

Comment: @SilentAssassin: Just started learning PHP, so playing the string and array functions.

Comment: I want to first convert the string to array then reverse the array, then put space at the defined index and then print the output in original order with space. Ex: stackoverflowdescription --> noitpircsedwolfrevokcats --> noitpircsed wolf revo kcats --> stack over flow description

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$output = implode(" ", $yourArrayOfWords);
?>
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch.  This is the same as @deceze `join()`.

Comment: Except that @deceze put it in the comment and not the answer.

Comment: Hehe :) yeah `join` is an alias of `implode`

Comment: I want to first convert the string to array then reverse the array, then put space at the defined index and then print the output in original order with space. Ex: stackoverflowdescription --> noitpircsedwolfrevokcats --> noitpircsed wolf revo kcats --> stack over flow description